# Unable to access system site packages inside virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, tensorrt

Global python

`which python3.6`

Gives

`/usr/bin/python3`

Inside global python3

`import tensorrt`

Works fine, but creating virtual environment

`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 --system-site-packages test`

inside virtualenv

`import tensorrt`

`No module named 'tensorrt'`

Answer (score 0):

what python path you use globally? is it the same `/usr/bin/python3`?